# Tabulator Multiselect - How to set a list of default values and display them in the header filter?

Tags: tabulator

I have a multiselect header filter in my Tabulator table initialized as so:

```
 {
     title: "Building",
     field: "Building",
     headerFilter: true,
     editor: "select",
     headerFilterParams: {
         values: buildings, 
         multiselect:true, //allow multiple entries to be selected
     }
 }
```

After the table initialization, I tried to set the filters for the building column as such

```
table.setFilter("Building", "in", userBuildings);
table.refreshFilter();
```

The filters are successfully submitted back to the server for filtering, but are not displayed in the table header. I can't find any reference to set the defaultValue field to an array and was wondering if anyone knows of a way to achieve that.

Thanks in advance!